# How do i get just 1 element JS

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add hcaptcha to my website but i am doing it in a strange way i want to get if the div with the class 'check' is hidden or not but i cannot do it.
here is my code

```
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("check")[0]
    var y = window.getComputedStyle(x).display
    alert(y)
```

it gives me the error     'cip.html:62 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at cip.html:62'

Comment: You must not have an element with class="check" in your html.

Comment: When do you run that code?

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify that x is not undefined in case none of the elements have the class your looking for

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("check")[0]
if (x) {
  var y = window.getComputedStyle(x).display
  alert(y)
} else {
  alert('not found')
}
```